# Does Marketo support CORS?

Tags: cors, marketo

I am trying to build a basic web-app, accessing the REST API with AngularJS.

Does Marketo's server recognise a CORS request? I can't seem to get it to work. Is there a trick to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Marketo will not support CORS.  Trying to make REST requests from the browser exposes your access token and would be a big security hole.